# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck before login

Tags: dual-boot, login, 20.04, thinkpad, boot-repair

Each time I reboot the Ubuntu, it will stuck after the grub interface and before login.

[image: See here the photo]

I tried the boot-repair software but it doesn't help. I can only enter the Ubuntu with recovery mode.

My computer is Thinkpad T480s with integrated graphics, and I have dual OS (Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10) in separate disks.

Update: After trying several times the boot-repair software, I can now login by chance, which means sometimes I can successfully boot but sometimes I cannot. It is really wierd. When it get stuck, I press 'Esc' but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: at that screen in pic.. can you press esc key and see are there any clues of error msgs?

Comment: Thanks I finally solved the problem by running boot-repair several times. The problem might be that the EFI system can was not mounted before when booting.

Comment: Do you feel confident adding an answer with what you did to solve it?

Comment: I had similar problems when installing ubuntu desktop 20.04 on a server with only vga graphics. It turned out that after installing ubuntu server 20.04 it worked without problems. Also, I could boot to console with the desktop version of ubuntu. So if you try to install a server edition (that boots to console by default) or change the boot parameters of your current ubuntu edition (by pressing Esc or Shift when booting) to boot to console (text / textonly next to quiet or quiet splash), you can find out if your problem is related to the gui. With the console, you at least have a running ubuntu

Comment: I met the same problem on my Lenovo Thinkpad T480s with NVIDIA Geforce MX150. After I installed Ubuntu20.04 on my laptop, I could login and use the system. But after updating software and restarting the computer, I was stuck at Ubuntu 20.04 welcome screen forever. Is there anybody know the root cause and give some advice? Thank you!